# Compare two datasets and create a formula to adjust one of the datasets

Tags: excel, arduino, dataset, formula

I have two datasets, or two columns in excel. Column 1 is a Temperature value and column 2 is the value of a load cell. Anyone who has used a load cell before knows that the load cell value changes with temperature.

I need to be able to find or create a formula that will compensate the load cell value based on the temperature reading. As you can see from the attached chart, there is a strong link between Temperature (Orange) and the Load Cell (Grey).

I have tried to find information about this on the internet but I can't find anything definitive, but maybe I am not asking the right question. I need to use the formula in Arduino code.

Any help would be greatly appreciated. I am not sure how to attach the dataset spreadsheet on here otherwise I would include that.

[image: chart]

Comment: Are you searching for something that generate a plain graph after its use? More info of the sensors, please.

Comment: I need to be able to have a formula that will use the temperature values to compensate for the drift in the load cell...so for example when the temperature in the graph I attached is at 34 degrees, the load cell is reading 3.44, I need to be able to use the temperature of 34 degrees to get the load cell as close to zero as possible.

Comment: The sensors aren't really relevant I don't think, It's just a temperature sensor and a load cell. Load cells 'drift' with temperature so there needs to be a way of compensating for it.

Comment: "" I need to be able to use the temperature of 34 degrees to get the load cell as close to zero as possible."" This was my question. OK so you need to find the math relation (direct, geometrical, exponential...) Looks like something like a simple direct relation. I can't explain anything now. Could you post a file for testing some ideas?

Comment: This remembers me to ANOVA. Have you ever done an ANOVA?